# How to prevent QWidget inside QTabWidget from being expanded to equal size of largest item in QTabWidget?

Tags: qt, pyqt

Using pyqt, I have something like:

```
class Wid(QtGui.QWidget)  ...

tabs_window = QtGui.QTabWidget()        

for w in list_of_Wids:
    tabs_window.addTab(w, w.name)
```

The Wid objects are all different sizes, so pyqt scales the QTabWidget to be large enough to fit the largest size.  My problem is that the smaller Wid objects are all scaled up to this size, and look ugly.

How can I force each Wid object to be its 'normal' size, and just have blank space in the remaining area?

Comment: Create a new widget, this new widget has a vertical layout, in this layout, has the smallest widget, plus spacer. Instead of adding the smallest widget directly, add this new widget into the tab widget.

Comment: Presumably, each widget has its own layout - so all you need to do is add an expanding spacer to the bottom and/or right-hand side of that layout.

Comment: Hi user3183610 - I used your method, thankyou.